# ¿Cómo generar un archivo a partir de una platilla en TXT con una estructura determinada?

Tags: python-3.x, template, doctest

Después de buscar en diversos foros, grupos, en buscadores, libros de texto en Python (si, soy así de clásico, pero nunca se sabe) no encuentro solución a un problema concreto.

Les pongo en contexto:

1. Es Python 3.5
2. Es una pequeña extensión de un framework para test de QA en Python que trabaja sobre archivos '*.feature' en Gerhkin para el framework de Python Behave.
3. Para hacer más fácil la tarea y automatizar más el framework hemos extendido con un archivo python la funcionalidad del mismo en un intento de poder generar más archivos '*.feature' a partir de un simple archivo 'list.txt'
4. Funcionamiento: es simple en idea. Despues de leer la documentación de un proyecto a someter a pruebas se crea un 'list.txt' en donde bajo una notación para indexar y anidar la estructura de datos tipo esqueleto en archivo '*.feature'. Lee por un orden determinado para según el algoritmo desarrollado el crear lineas de texto y anidaras según el orden dado. El problema es que el enfoque ahora es combinatorio y generar lineas que no son necesarias.
5. Ejemplo de 'list.txt': [enlace](https://pastebin.com/k1x3wskS)
6. Código hasta ahora desarrollado (disculpen el exceso de documetación): [enlace](https://pastebin.com/sQD5aHAA)
7. Y el hipotético resultado que debe salir (no coincide con el 'list.txt' de arriba, pero es para que vean el objetivo de indentación etc):[enlace](https://pastebin.com/dyZc0mFF)
8. Se ha usado Doctest para desarrollo, documentación y testing del código.
9. Enlace de Behave aquí, para que vean cómo son los feature:[enlace](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Un cordial saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Saludos y bienvenido a la comunidad, te invito a leer [ask], si pudieras editar y agregar aquí mismo como texto el código sería genial, recuerda para darle formato basta con seleccionarlo y presionar `ctrl + k`

Answer (score 0):

Tras analizar mi software encontré una solución alternatíva más sencilla y corta aunque menos elegante.
El enlace a pastebin [aquí](https://pastebin.com/iJerzqzR).

Se puede refinar paro actua análogo a una pila de tareas con respecto a las líneas del texto.

Comment: En lugar del enlace a pastebin, tu respuesta quedaria mucho mejor si adjuntas el codigo aqui :)